# Can i incorporate my Python script on a Webpage using Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm really new to Python in general and i was learning about python for web developing and Django. I made a simple Python scripts which outputs some data every second, i was looking for a way to have this data printed on a dynamic web page, this is how i found about Django. From what i understood, Django is a library for web developing with Python, so i think it could be what i'm looking for.

My question is: how would exactly Django work for this? Could i just "incorporate" my script into my Django project and then use Django for the frontend?

Comment: You can't run python on the browser, only javascript.  You can however have javascript poll the server and feed the data back to javascript to display on a webpage.  I recommend taking a look at [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to help you build an API that you can query from Javascript.

Comment: Problem is: how fast would this be? My script is receiving data from a websocket, from that i'd need to print everything on a webpage the fastest i can, since speed is essential for what i'm trying to build

Comment: If you want a constant stream then a websocket is reasonable'ish since it is most like a straight TCP connection.  I think you can do websockets with Django, but I haven't tried.  Doing a REST API is useful for a lot of things and polling your server with GET requests for your data does work fine.

Comment: Ok! When you said "you can have js poll the server", what server are you talking about?

Comment: having "up to the second" dynamic data on a webpage is going to be pretty intensive. How many people would you expect to use your site at once? Seems like you'd ddos yourself pretty easily

Comment: @SuperStew I don't think i would have a lot of people visit the webpage at first, it's more of a task that i decided to do myself

Comment: @Sile, a webpage is served from a server like stackoverflow.com . Your users will need to go to some DNS ( www.example.com) or some IP (192.168.0.107) that goes to some computer serving up your page.  Once that page is loaded, the javascript can do [fetches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to that _same_ server under a different directory like www.example.com/rest/v1/FooData or 192.168.0.107/rest/v1/FooData.

Comment: @SuperStew, he's just getting started so I think he can cross the traffic bridge in the future.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks @SuperStew!